# RVM not picking up /etc/gemrc

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, rubygems, rvm, gem

in a system wide RVM ....
heres my /etc/gemrc

```
---
gem:--no-ri --no-rdoc
```

heres the system `gem env`

```
 GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/${USER}/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
    GEM CONFIGURATION:
         - :update_sources => true
         - :verbose => true
         - :benchmark => false
         - :backtrace => false
         - :bulk_threshold => 1000
         - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
```

and heres the one in rvm

```
GEM PATHS:
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
 - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
```

and rvm @global

```
    GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
```

why is it not picking up the gemrc file?

Answer (score 7):

Same here. Try this path:

`/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/etc/gemrc`

To get the path:

```
$ irb
>> require 'etc'
>> Etc.sysconfdir 
 => "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/etc"
```

Comment: that will sandbox it only to ruby-1.9.2-p180 correct?

Comment: @jtzero correct

Comment: see the problem with that is I don't want an rdocs on the server, on any version of ruby...

Answer (score 1):

you need to specify `--sysconfdir=/etc` for every ruby you compile, you could do that with:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 -C --sysconfdir=/etc
```

of course there was a bug in rubygems that caused all 1.8 rubies to use `/etc` it will be fixed with  https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/pull/291

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the gemrc file in /usr/local/etc - it should be picked up by all custom compiled rubies.

```
tee /usr/local/etc/gemrc <<EOF
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you're supposed to use the name of the command you want to add those arguments to, not `gem`.
For example:

```
---
install: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Note the `install`, instead of `gem`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something 1.9.2 related as rvm installed 1.8.7 is picking up the /etc/gemrc file
I ended up symlinking ~/.gemrc to /etc/gemrc

Comment: yeah that's my current work around however I have to do that for each dev-user that is created....I could make it so that every time a user is added to copy the symlink and it will work but I dont like it....